# Read two files from stdio

Tags: c++, input, stdin

I want to read from two files, one containing floats in three columns, and another containing ints in two columns. I have the following code to read from stdin:

```
int main() {
    while (scanf("%lf %lf %lf\n",&x,&y,&z) != EOF) {
        // do stuff
    }

    puts("foo");

    int a,b;
    while (scanf("%d %d\n",&a,&b) != EOF) {
        puts("bar");
    }
}
```

Then I call the program with `cat ortho.dat pairs.dat | ./angles`, ortho.dat and pairs.dat being the two files. However the output is just `foo` indicating that the second file is never read, presumably because it reads EOF and immediately terminates the second loop. Is this correct?

How could I read the two files, without actually opening them in the program, merely reading them from stdin?

Comment: 1. Decide on the programming language. 2.Pass the file names into the application can not use `cat`. 3. Read those files - that depends on the programming language

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the post itself, but the language is C++, as stated in the title and the tags. I also specifically said that I wanted to know how to do this from the shell, without files. That I know how to do :)

Comment: So why C in the title and tags if it is C++?

Comment: @andrepd I've retagged your question per your comment, however your question is more appropriate to C as you're not using C++ idiom. I **HIGHLY** suggest you pick the language for the idiom you intend to use.

Answer (score 3):

Question:

> How could I read the two files, without actually opening them in the program, merely reading them from `stdin`?

One solution:

Insert dummy, invalid, content between the contents of two files. 
Use it to separate the data from the first file and the second file.

Contents of file "dummy":

```
===Separator===
```

Change your code to:

```
int main() {
    while (scanf("%lf %lf %lf\n",&x,&y,&z) == 3) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // Skip the line that contains the separator.
    scanf("%*[^\n]");

    puts("foo");

    int a,b;
    while (scanf("%d %d\n",&a,&b) == 2) {
        puts("bar");
    }
}
```

Change the invocation:

```
cat ortho.dat dummy pairs.dat | ./angles
```

**Update**

A C++ version:

```
int main() {
    while ( std::cin >> x >> y >> z ) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // Skip the line that contains the separator.
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    puts("foo");

    int a,b;
    while ( std::cin >> a >> b ) {
        puts("bar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do "cat F1 F2 | program", cat will **concatenate** the files and the program will receive single continuous stream of data.

From the point of view of the program it is impossible to find where one file ends and second begins *unless* some marker inserted into the files.

For example, you can insert a single line after the first file saying:
    FILE1ENDS
Then, if such a line would never be found in the file itself you can use that to terminate your first loop.

As an alternative pass file names as arguments to your program and open/read/close them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that reliably. Read about 
 [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) (it handles every space-like character the same, including newlines). BTW, you'll better test that `scanf` returns the actual count (e.g. 3 for the first case, 2 for the second one).

However, you might have more constraints on the input. Perhaps the three doubles and the two integers are always on a single same line, e.g. `ortho.dat` containing lines like

```
1.0 2.0 3.0
```

and `pairs.dat` containing lines like

```
23 45
```

then you could read every line using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (or perhaps `fgets`) and use `sscanf` to parse it (and you would use its return count to separate the lines with 3 floating points from the lines with 2 integers). The `%n`  control format could perhaps be handy (it gives the current cursor position).

However, I would instead suggest to pass the two file names `ortho.dat` & `pairs.dat` as distinct arguments (i.e. use the conventional `argc` & `argv` arguments to `main(int argc, char**argv)`)